# How to change the series color and mark after I draw the line chart in highcharts?Does it has databound event?

Tags: highcharts, dotnethighcharts

How to change the series color and mark after I draw the line chart in highcharts?Does it has databound event? I get the json from the server,if my json do not defined the series color and mark,after draw some series can I change their color and mark(such as "circle","triangle","cross" and so on)?Now use this method,Why I can change the default color,but  can not change the default symbal of mark?

```
$(function () {
 var marks = new Array("square",  "diamond", "triangle");
Highcharts.setOptions({
    colors: ['red', '#50B432', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4'],
    symbol:marks
});

$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is available in the [`series.update()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update) method. You would do something like:

```
chart.series[0].update({
    color: color ? null : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
});
```

Where `series[0]` is the index of the series you want to update.

Comment: Hi,I use this method,I can change the default color,but I can not change the default symbal of the marks.Can you tell me why?http://jsfiddle.net/whoamiwho/3TBaq/

Comment: When you set the marker you need to set the whole array to one marker, or update individual points with a marker. You cannot set the `marker.symbol` to an array. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/3TBaq/2/

Comment: thanks,your method can update the symbol.But I have to update them after the series have been drawn,Does it has 'databound' event?

Comment: This does update them after they are created. Do you want to set the marker symbol at the same time they are created? If so set it in the series options for that series you want to change.

Comment: If you want to update the marker/color after the chart has finished loading you can just call the update in-line with the chart or with in the `chart.events.load` call - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.load